# How to open a terminal file in TextEdit

Tags: terminal, osx, nano

I use `nano <file_name>` to open/edit files on terminal. However it's very hard to edit so is there a way to open terminal files in TextEdit?

**EDIT:**

`open -a TextEdit <my_file_name>` and `open -a TextEdit` both return this:

```
open: invalid option -- 'a'
Usage: open [OPTIONS] -- command

This utility help you to start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).

Options:
  -c, --console=NUM   use the given VT number;
  -e, --exec          execute the command, without forking;
  -f, --force         force opening a VT without checking;
  -l, --login         make the command a login shell;
  -u, --user          figure out the owner of the current VT;
  -s, --switch        switch to the new VT;
  -w, --wait          wait for command to complete;
  -v, --verbose       print a message for each action;
  -V, --version       print program version and exit;
  -h, --help          output a brief help message.
```

`open -e <my_file_name>` returns:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Comment: `open -a TextEdit filename` Taken from: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25844/can-i-open-files-in-textedit-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Both not working for me (shown in my edit). Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like you have something called `openvt` installed that perhaps is linked as `open`? What happens if you run `which open`? By default on OSX it should point to `/usr/bin/open`. What happens if you try `/usr/bin/open -a TextEdit filename`?

Comment: My server is set like this: `/home/user/project_name/env/bin` so I did `/james/postr/env/bin/open -a TextEdit settings.py` which returned `-bash: /james/postr/env/bin/open: No such file or directory`. There is no `open` file in my `bin` directory.

Comment: I tried the alternate method in the link you posted - I added `alias textedit='open -a TextEdit'` to my `.profile`. After that I tested it with `textedit settings.py` and it returned `The program 'textedit' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install xview-clients`. So I installed it - but after I tried `textedit settings.py` again, it returned `XView error: Cannot open connection to window server: :0 (Server package)`. Any idea?

Comment: I'm confused, what are you using? You have this tagged as `osx` but it is telling you about `apt install` which sounds like some type of Debian/Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this is on Ubuntu 16.04 on my remote Digital Ocean server. The method you told me works on offline on my Mac OSX.

Comment: Please fix your tags so as to avoid wasting your time and the time of colleagues who try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Ubuntu, there is no `textedit` command or application out of the box.

From your question:

1. `open -e settings.py`
   On osx, this would execute the python file instead of opening it in your default text editor.
   Use `open -t settings.py` to open the python file with the default text editor.
2. `open -a TextEdit`
   This doesn't work op Ubuntu because TextEdit simply doesn't exist (works on mac).
   For your purpose, try `gedit settings.py`
3. `xdg-open settings.py`
   On Ubuntu, try xdg-open. This is the equivalent of Macs' `open` command which opens any file with the associated default application for the file type.
   I'm not sure what application would launch if you try to open a python file though.